# useContext Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-hooks

I am trying to implement authentication with Firebase in a React Native Expo App but am getting an error pointing to `useContext`, which I am using in my Routes.js file:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

import AuthStack from './AuthStack';
import MainTab from './MainTab';
import { AuthUserContext } from './AuthUserProvider';
import LoadingScreen from '../screens/LoadingScreen';

export default function Routes() {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const { user, setUser } = useContext(AuthUserContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribeAuth = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async authUser => {
            try {
                await (authUser ? setUser(authUser) : setUser(null));
                setIsLoading(false);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
        return unsubscribeAuth;
    }, []);

    if (isLoading) {
        return <LoadingScreen />;
    }

    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            {user ? <MainTab /> : <AuthStack />}
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

I create `AuthUserContext` in a separate file `AuthUserProvider.js`:

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';

export const AuthUserContext = createContext({});

export const AuthUserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  return (
    <AuthUserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      {children}
    </AuthUserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

which I then use as a provider in my App.js file:

```
export default function AppWrapper() {
  const [fontLoaded, setFontLoaded] = useState(false);

  if (!fontLoaded) {
    return (
      <AppLoading 
        startAsync={fetchFonts} 
        onFinish={() => setFontLoaded(true)} 
      />
    );
  }

  const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    cart: cartReducer,
    history: historyReducer
  });
  
  const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <AuthUserProvider>
        <Routes />
      </AuthUserProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

I've been searching for an answer for days and can't see what's wrong with this. Is there a problem with the way I am using `createContext` or `useContext`? Any leads on a possible solution would make me eternally grateful!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a high chance the error is from Redux, `store` and `rootReducer` should be in outer scope:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  cart: cartReducer,
  history: historyReducer,
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

export default function AppWrapper() {
  const [fontLoaded, setFontLoaded] = useState(false);

  if (!fontLoaded) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={fetchFonts}
        onFinish={() => setFontLoaded(true)}
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <AuthUserProvider>
        <Routes />
      </AuthUserProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, still getting the error though. Is there a problem with having two providers as I do in my `AppWrapper`?

Comment: Do you have context in AppLoading?... Please just make a reproducible example in codesandbox so we won't guess